# 'pathExtension' is unavailable: Use pathExtension on URL instead

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

This code gives an error 'pathExtension' is unavailable: Use pathExtension on URL instead:

```
if originalAudioFormat == "MP2" || originalAudioFormat == "BWFMP2" {
                    SourceFileNameWithPath = decodeMp2ToWav() 

                        if SourceFileNameWithPath.pathExtension != "wav" { //error at this line
                            print("save File as PCM Fehler: \(SourceFileNameWithPath)")
                            return
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's highly recommended to prefer always `URL`s to `String` paths.

Alternatively you can bridge the string to `NSString`

```
(SourceFileNameWithPath as NSString).pathExtension
```

Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.